# Is there a better way to declare a numpy matrix where each element [i][j] is the result of an operation between A[i] and A[j], where A is an arange?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, 2d

Basically, what I need to do is this:

- I have a value "n" and two different arrays "x" and "y" of arbitrary values (x,y = [a, b, c, ...])
- With n, I create an arange "A" like this: [n, n-1, n-2, ..., 0]
- I create a 2d array "B" of size n+1×n+1 where each element B[i][j] = np.sum(np.power(x,(A[i]+A[j])))
- I create a 1d array "C" of size n+1 where each element C[i] = np.sum(np.power(x,A[i])*y)

For example, for n = 1, x = [0, 1, 2] and y = [3, 7, 0]:

- A = [1, 0]
- B = [[(np.sum(np.power([0, 1, 2],(1+1)))), (np.sum(np.power([0, 1, 2],(1+0))))],[(np.sum(np.power([0, 1, 2],(0+1)))), (np.sum(np.power([0, 1, 2],(0+0))))]]
- C = [(np.sum(np.power([0, 1, 2],1)*[3, 7, 0])),(np.sum(np.power([0, 1, 2],0)*[3, 7, 0]))]

What's the "cleanest" way of doing this with numpy and Python 3.11?

What I ended up doing is:

```
A = np.arange(n,-1,-1)
B = np.zeros(((n+1),(n+1)))
C = np.zeros (((n+1),1))
for i in range(n+1):
    for j in range(n+1):
        B[i][j] = np.sum(np.power(x,(A[i]+A[j])))
    C[i] = np.sum(np.power(x,A[i])*y)
```

But I feel like this is an inefficient/"ugly" way of doing it

EDIT:
@mozway suggested the following code:

```
x = np.array(x)
A = np.array(A)

B = (x**(A[:,None]+A)[..., None]).sum(-1)

y = np.array(y)

C = (x**A[:, None]*y).sum(-1)
```

However, that's giving me the following error for `n = 1`, `A = np.arange(n,-1,-1)`, `x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` and `y = np.array([1.3, 1.8, 2.2, 0.4, 1.1, 3.0, 1.1, 0.8, 0.1])`:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (9,) (2,)

Comment: Try to express the task in whole array terms.  `C=A[:,None]+A` is the same as the `A[i]+A[j]` iteration.  Have you read the beginners/essentials docs?

Comment: @hpaulj you mean doing this instead?
A = np.arange(n,-1,-1)
    B = np.zeros(((n+1),(n+1)))
    C = np.zeros (((n+1),1))
    B = np.sum(np.power(x,(A[:,None]+A)))
    C[i] = np.sum(np.power(x,A)*y)
Also, I read some of the docs

Comment: If `A` has shape (2,), the `A[:,None]+A` will be (2,2), and `sum(-1)` brings it back to (2,).  `x` is (9,).  You can't mix the 2.   `x[:,None]**(...)` would make a (9,2) result.  Test  your calculations step by step, in small pieces, where you can track the values, and especially the shapes.  Don't code big blocks without first testing the individual steps.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you. What would you suggest in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

```
x = np.array(x)
A = np.array(A)

B = (x**(A[:,None]+A)[..., None]).sum(-1)

y = np.array(y)

C = (x**A[:, None]*y).sum(-1)
```

Output:

```
# B
array([[5, 3],
       [3, 3]])

# C
array([ 7, 10])
```

###### other example

```
n = 1
A = np.arange(n,-1,-1)
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
y = np.array([1.3, 1.8, 2.2, 0.4, 1.1, 3.0, 1.1, 0.8, 0.1])

B = (x**(A[:,None]+A)[..., None]).sum(-1)
# array([[285,  45],
#        [ 45,   9]])

C = (x**A[:, None, None]*y).sum(-1)
# array([[51.6],
#        [11.8]])
```

Comment: I'm not sure why but but it's not working properly, Python says "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (9,) (2,)
            ~^^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,) (3,)"

Comment: Can you provide the complete (yet minimal) code that reproduces this error? I tested it with other `n` and this gives the same output as your loop.

Comment: I'm somewhat new to StackOverflow, Is there a better way to post code other than in the comments? It gets all messed up.

Comment: Yes, edit your question.

Comment: I just edited it. I would share the full code, however, since it is for a college assignment, the variables, comments and functions are all in Portuguese. x, y and n are provided by another function, and the names "A", "B" and "C" were changed for the post, but other than that, it's pretty much just the code that's already in the question, at least for this specific function (it receives X and Y data and calculates the linear fit for a polynomial of degree n).

Comment: @Victor I don't have an error with your provided code (see update in answer). I would just change `C` to `C = (x**A[:, None, None]*y).sum(-1)`